# can i check before add new marker whether at this location other marker already added or not?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I work on google map .I add Markers first with type and then add marker again with distance so problem is there at some location two markers are add . so when i click on that it alternatively change. so i need to check marker is already there or not when add with distance.thanx.

Comment: Please show relevant portions of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best way is to store already added markers to a collection, and then search for equal markers.

```
ArrayList<Marker> collection = new ArrayList()<Marker>;
collection.add(map.addMarker(Marker));
```

Something like this to add items, and then a function to check if exists

```
static boolean isMarkerOnArray(ArrayList<Marker> array, Marker m)
{
    for(int c=0;c<array.size();c++)
    {
        Marker current = array.get(c);
        if((current.getPosition().latitude == m.getPosition().latitude) &&(current.getPosition().longitude == m.getPosition().longitude) )
            return true;    //Both markers are equal
    }
return false;
}
```

HandWrite code, it can be wrong, but i think thats the proper way to do it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: static boolean isMarkerOnArray(List<Marker> array, Object m)
    {
        for(Marker marker : array)
        {
            if((marker.getPosition().latitude == m.getLatitude()) &&(marker.getPosition().longitude == m.getLongitude())) {
                return true;    //Both markers are equal
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

Is better :)